# pass variable in to command in python

Tags: python, freeswitch

i'm writing a python script to execute shell command, and i'm taking arguments and i want to pass the value of that to the command

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import commands
import subprocess
import sys

command = commands.getoutput('fs_cli -x "sofia profile external restart"')
```

this code works fine

when i try to take the argument and pass to command it fails

> command = commands.getoutput('fs_cli -x "sofia profile" + sys.argv[1]
>   + " restart"')

supp folks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write:

```
command = commands.getoutput('fs_cli -x "sofia profile ' + sys.argv[1] + ' restart"')
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [*argparse*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) and [*subprocess*](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html).

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to do this is to convert your command that you want to execute into string and then execute it as eval()

example :
eval(expression/command in string)